# Why is my CPU Performance of Float64 tf.matmul in TensorFlow2 significantly slower than the NumPy matmul, even in the graph mode?

Tags: numpy, performance, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, intel-mkl

I'm comparing the single thread performance of the matrix-matrix products in **TensorFlow 2** and **NumPy**. I compare separately for single precision (float32) and double precision (float64). I find that the **NumPy** performance is almost equivalent to the Intel MKL C++ implementation (used as a benchmark for matrix multiplication) for both single and double precision (DGEMM and SGEMM). But in **TensorFlow**, only the single precision (float32) performance is equivalent to the MKL, and the double precision (float64) performance is significantly slower. **Why is Tensorflow slower when used with double precision data?**

**Sample Scripts:**

I consider the following instance to reproduce my observation. Consider the matrix multiplication:

> **C = AB** where A and B are of size 3000x3000

The TensorFlow2 and NumPy code are given below:

***Tensorflow2 code***

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import time


#Check if MKL is enabled
import tensorflow.python.framework as tff
print("MKL Enabled : ", tff.test_util.IsMklEnabled())


#Set threads
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1)
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1)

#Problem size
N = 3000
REPS = 20
DTYPE = tf.float64
#DTYPE = tf.float32


@tf.function
def gemm_implicit_noup(A, B):
    #C = A @ B
    start = tf.timestamp()
    with tf.control_dependencies([start]):
        C = tf.matmul(A,B)
    with tf.control_dependencies([C]):
        end = tf.timestamp()
    tf.print(end-start)
    return C

tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(False)

A = tf.random.normal([N, N], dtype=DTYPE)
B = tf.random.normal([N, N], dtype=DTYPE)


#Building Trace
C = gemm_implicit_noup(A,B)

for i in range(REPS):
   C = gemm_implicit_noup(A,B)
```

***Numpy code***

```py
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
import numpy as np
import time

N = 3000
REPS = 20
DTYPE = np.float64
#DTYPE = np.float32

def gemm_implicit_noup(A, B):
    #C = A @ B
    C = np.matmul(A,B)
    return C



A = np.random.randn(N,N).astype(DTYPE)
B = np.random.randn(N,N).astype(DTYPE)

for i in range(REPS):
   start = time.perf_counter()
   C = gemm_implicit_noup(A,B)
   end = time.perf_counter()
   print(end-start)
```

**System and Installation settings:**

The performance was compared on Intel Xeon Skylake 2.1 GHz with CentOS 7 and also on MacBook Pro 2018 with BigSur. The performance was compared on both **Tensorflow 2.7** and **2.8**, which were built with Intel MKL. **Python 3.9.7** and **3.7.4** were checked. I compare the single thread performance so that the results can be reliably reproduced. I observe similar performance numbers in all the settings:

Single precision performance is as expected:

- Intel MKL C++ SGEMM ~ **0.5s**
- NumPy float32 ~ **0.5s**
- TensorFlow float32 ~ **0.5s**

But Double precision performance:

- Intel MKL C++ DGEMM ~ **0.9s**
- NumPy float64 ~ **1s**
- TensorFlow float64 > **2.5s** (Much Slower!!)

Comment: `numpy` is linked to either OpenBLAS or MKL and directly calls `gemm`. IIRC, TensorFlow uses Eigen's tensor math library (unless you've enabled CUDA). I would assume it's a difference in performance in the linked libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are using an **Intel® AVX-512** instruction-supported processor, try installing the **Intel® Optimization for TensorFlow** Wheel via PIP specifically build for AVX512. These packages are available as *.whl on the Intel® website for specific Python versions or can be installed using the following command for Python versions 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9 (Linux Only).

```
pip install intel-tensorflow-avx512==2.7.0
```

This is documented on the official Intel® website and its sub-sections given in the below links:

[Intel® Optimization for TensorFlow: Installation Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide.html)

[Intel® Optimization for TensorFlow: Install the Intel® Optimization for TensorFlow Wheel via PIP](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide.html#collapseCollapsible1638468586913)

**AVX512** is a [Single Instruction Multiple Data (SIMD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) instruction set specifically designed to handle complex data types like double-precision numbers. In order to take full advantage of Intel® architecture and to extract maximum performance, the TensorFlow framework has been optimized using **[oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onednn.html)** primitives, a popular performance library for deep learning applications. As an additional optimization step, also try setting the environment variable **TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS to 1** inside your Linux terminal using the following command before running the TensorFlow code:

```
export TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=1
```

The single-thread performance obtained for double-precision matrix-matrix products using the code that you provided is given below. This test is done on an *Intel® Xeon® Platinum 8260M CPU @ 2.40GHz* with *Python 3.8* along with *Intel® MKL and *AVX512* optimized TensorFlow 2.7*.

- NumPy float64 ~ **1.44s**
- TensorFlow float64 (MKL Enabled) ~ **2.77s**
- TensorFlow float64 (MKL Enabled, AVX512 Optimized, oneDNN Optimization Enabled) ~ **1.19s**